# System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001 Class.CollectionMaster.getCollectionMaster: line 17, column 1

Tags: limitexception

```
    @RestResource(urlMapping='/CollectionMaster/*')
    global with sharing class CollectionMaster{

    @HttpPOST
    global static CollectionWrapper getCollectionMaster(String userName){ 
         list<Product__c> crList;
         list<Product__c> crList1;
         User ur=[select id,Region__c,UserRole.name from  user where Username=:userName];
            if(ur.UserRole.name =='SR')
       {

          crList= [select id,Brand__c,Category__c,Collection__c,Collection_Name__c from Product__c];
          crList1= [select id,Brand__c,Category__c,Collection__c,Collection_Name__c from Product__c];
       }
      else if(ur.UserRole.name =='RSM'){
      crList= [select id,Brand__c,Category__c,Collection__c,Collection_Name__c  from Product__c LIMIt 50000];
       system.debug('***RSM***');
        } else if(ur.UserRole.name =='HOD' || ur.UserRole.name =='MD'){
           crList= [select id,Brand__c,Category__c,Collection__c,Collection_Name__c from Product__c];
           }
list<Brand_Ranking__c>brList=[select id,Brand__c,Ranking__c from Brand_Ranking__c order By Ranking__c desc]; 

        set<String> categoryList1= new set<String>();
        set<String> categoryArrayList= new set<String>();
        set<String> collectionList1= new set<String>();
        set<String> collectionArrayList= new set<String>();
        CollectionWrapper cc=new CollectionWrapper();
          cc.categoryList =new list<String>();
            cc.collectionList=new list<String>();
         system.debug('Category list*******'+crList);
       if(ur.UserRole.name =='SR')
       {
         for(Product__c pd:crList){
         String[] colArray = pd.Collection_Name__c.split('\\;');
          for(String col:colArray )
             {
              collectionList1.add(pd.Collection_Name__c);
              collectionList1.add(col);
             }
         } 

         for(Product__c pd1:crList1){
          String[] colArray2 = pd1.Product__c.split('\\;');
              for(String col:colArray2 )
            {
                categoryArrayList.add(col);
            }
         }



             for(Brand_Ranking__c pdd:brList)
         {
            for(string st:categoryArrayList)
            {
              if(st==pdd.Category__c)
             categoryList1.add(st);
            }
         }


           }else
       {
         for(Product__c pd:crList){
          String[] warArray4 = pd.Collection_Name__c.split('\\;');
         for(String col:warArray4 )
          {
              collectionList1.add(col);
            }

        String[] warArray1 = pd.Product__c.split('\\;');
          for(String col:warArray1 )
            {
              categoryArrayList.add(col);
            } 

         for(Brand_Ranking__c pdd:brList)
          {
            for(string st:categoryArrayList)
          {
              if(st==pdd.Product__c)
        categoryList1.add(st);
            }
         }


        }
        }



       system.debug('categoryList1/********'+categoryList1);
        system.debug('collectionList1/********'+collectionList1);
         categoryList1.remove(null);
           collectionList1.remove(null);
            cc.categoryList.addAll(categoryList1);
              cc.collectionList.addAll(collectionList1);
         return cc;
      }


        global class CollectionWrapper{
       public list<String>categoryList;
        public list<String>collectionList;

       }
    }
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying system.limitexception : Too many query rows 50001 someone please help me with this I'm stuck here since few days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this Error because the SOQL query is returning more than **50K** records.

As a best practice put the Limit in your SOQL or filter the records using Where Clause so that it does not hit the governor limit.

> Example Query Using Limit

```
select id,Brand__c,Category__c,Collection__c,Collection_Name__c from Product__c LImit 50000
```

> Example Query using Where and Limit Clause

```
select id,Brand__c,Category__c,Collection__c,Collection_Name__c from Product__c Where Brand__c='Value here' LIMIT 50000
```

Refer below link for more information
[SOQL Best Practice for Large Dataset](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_best_practices_soql_and_sosl.htm)

Comment: LIMIT 5000 is not working i tried

Answer (score 0):

This Limit Error

> Too many query rows: 50001

is caused by your **SOQL queries** (note the plural). If we look at the documentation [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm), we will find one of the Per-Transaction Apex Limits states:

> Total number of records retrieved by SOQL queries - 50,000

This implies if you have 2 different queries each returning 30,000 records, you will hit this Limit because you'd have queried 60,000 records in total.

What you really want to do is set a limit for all of your queries to guarantee that in total they won't return more than 50,000 record. As another approach you could utilize the [Limits Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm) to dynamically (at the runtime) define the number of query rows your SOQL query can retrieve.

Generally, as a best practice you should try adding conditions in the WHERE part of your SOQLs to reduce the number of rows. That would return only records your code really need, instead of all records.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the result of the Query with different list variables as below:

```
 crList= [select id,Brand__c,Category__c,Collection__c,Collection_Name__c from Product__c limit 50000];
 if(ur.UserRole.name =='SR')
 {          
      crList1= crList.clone();
 }
 else if(ur.UserRole.name =='RSM'){
     system.debug('***RSM***');
 } else if(ur.UserRole.name =='HOD' || ur.UserRole.name =='MD'){
       system.debug('***HOD***MD***');
 }
```